# Build and override a simple Winelib DLL

Tags: windows, dll, wine, getprocaddress, winelib

I have a Windows executable that load a library and I want to create a Winelib DLL that will overide the Windows DLL.  It's been 2 days that I search and try but it won't work ! Please help me !

Basically I create mydll.c and mydll.spec to build the Winelib DLL with the command:

```
winegcc -m32 -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.c mydll.spec
```

Now I have **mydll.dll.so** and I want to override **mydll.dll** (both are at the same place)
What should I do ? I try to rename mydll.dll but I got a Page Fault when the function is called ! I also tried to configure the override with winecfg or set environment variables like WINEDLLPATH. I don't understand how to proceed.

---

How I load the library in my Windows executable

```
HINSTANCE DllHandle;
char str[255];
typedef int(__stdcall * tfp)(char * const);
DllHandle = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
tfp fp = (tfp)GetProcAddress(DllHandle, "myfunc");
fp(str);
FreeLibrary(DllHandle);
```

mydll.spec

```
@ stdcall myfunc(str)
```

mydll.c

```
#include <windef.h>

int WINAPI myfunc(char * str)
{
  strcpy(str, "myfunc from the Winelib DLL");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I corrected two mistakes, mylib should be mydll and you are missing a __stdcall, without which it causes a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WINEDEBUG=+module` to debug DLL loading problems.

I don't believe Wine searches for native `.dll.so` files outside of a single folder but the code is in [`dlls/ntdll/loader.c:load_builtin_dll`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/bedfb9cae224a369efa4588332a5518dbee57035/dlls/ntdll/loader.c#L2354) if you want to check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work but had to make the following changes.

I was using wine5 on Ubuntu, where is seems the default install is 64bit.  I had to rename wine's executable first as it was using the 32bit call by mistake and that meant it would not work with the 64bit dll.

install wine-tools (for winegcc)

```
apt-get install wine-tools
```

Fix wine64 (as the exe seems to load wine32 and then error)

```
cd /usr/lib/wine
mv wine wine32
ln -s wine64 wine
```

Makefile

```
all:    mydll.dll.so testmydll.exe

mydll.dll.so:   mydll.c mydll.spec
        winegcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.c mydll.spec

testmydll.exe:  testmydll.c
        winegcc -mno-cygwin -o testmydll testmydll.c

clean:
        rm -f *.so
        rm -f *.exe
        rm -f *~
```

Also, there is a mistake in your code, which I corrected. The lack of a __stdcall and the name of the DLL.